# custom fancyBox displaying SyntaxError and TypeError in live deployment, works locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools, fancybox-2

I'm testing fancyBox for the first time and I've run into a hurdle.

Following instructions on the developers [website](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) I've played around with the options you can pass to the fancybox() method so that only the primary image is displayed, and it retrieves information from an element rather than an attribute tag.

It works perfectly locally, as can be seen here:

[image]

But the same can't be said when I went live as you'll painfully see [***here.***](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/about.php)

Chrome's JS console is saying the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.fancybox.js:3

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js:3

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' about.php:302
(anonymous function) about.php:302
c jquery.js:3074
p.fireWith jquery.js:3186
x.extend.ready jquery.js:433
q jquery.js:104
```

The unexpected token is apparently from `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I feel it's down to my script arrangement, or lack of......

My current arrangement:

**Header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

**Body**

```
    <figure class="col-8 img-wrapper">

        <a class="fancybox fancybox-thumb" data-title-id="title-1" href="img/gym-01.jpg"><img class="img" src="img/gym-01.jpg" alt=""/></a>
        <div id="title-1" class="hidden">
            This is 1st title. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
        </div>

    </figure>

    <div class="hidden">

        <a class="fancybox fancybox-thumb" data-title-id="title-2" href="img/gym-02.jpg"><img src="img/gym-02.jpg" alt=""/></a>
        <div id="title-2" class="hidden">
            This is <b>2nd title</b>. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
        </div>

        <a class="fancybox fancybox-thumb" data-title-id="title-2" href="img/gym-03.jpg"><img src="img/gym-03.jpg" alt=""/></a>
        <div id="title-3" class="hidden">
            This is <b>3rd title</b>. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Footer**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js contains my custom fancyBox options.

Is it something daft that I'm missing????

Cheers guys!!

EDIT: It was simply an issue with the source path

Comment: Knowing Fancybox, it sometimes (strangely) throws a javascript error when your CSS setup is failing. Are you sure you've included the correct CSS file?

Comment: http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js - Check the contents of this file.

Comment: @RomanGorbatko I've commented on Natasha's Q below

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen both the CSS and JS files seem to be incorrect, however locally they're fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js and http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7 contain HTML, not JS.

Comment: Look my last comment :)

Comment: I'm lost - my src is fancybox/source/fancybox.js and fancybox/source/fancybox-thumbs.js, but both of those link to a HTML file as well....the files on my system are JS :) Any ideas????

Comment: The same is happening with the CSS files linked to fancyBox

Comment: it was simply just something strange going on the fancybox/.... folder path.... sorted now, cheers for the help